# Text Breaking DIV tag

Tags: html

I created a parent div with an image on top of it.  The image is obeying responsive rules on WordPress by contracting and expanding.  The Child div has text that is breaking the image div tag.

```
<div id="msegtable">

        <div class="msegment"><img src="PICTURE" />
        </div>

        <div class="msegtop">
High performance embedded technology from Corvalent is unlocking new oil and gas resources globally. Proudly made in the heart of oil country,long-life rugged computing solutions from Texas-based Corvalent significantly reduce cost of system ownership and protect revenue by ensuring non-stop performance of oil operations. As trusted advisors to the oil and gas OEM community, Corvalent readily integrates customers’ IP as part of system development – creating compatible plug-and-play solutions that refresh systems, streamline part numbers, reduce development time and assure simple onsite integration.
        </div>

        <div class="msegmid">• Long-life, rugged computing solutions developed along the Texas Gulf Coast and deployed in some of the most dangerous, remote and technically sophisticated environments on earth<br>
• Environmentally-certified solutions, validated for shock and vibration, dust and corrosion, and extreme temperatures<br>
• Customized solutions ensure system compatibility and avoid onsite system add-ons<br>
• Reduce development time and integration headaches with a valuable design and manufacturing partnership<br>
• Expertise in applications such as chemical analysis, fracking data collection, undersea robotic equipment, subsea systems, onshore/offshore surface logging and much more.
        </div>
        <div class="msegbottom">    
<p>“We use Corvalent in the field inside our logging boxes. The reliability and stability Corvalent provides allows us to be consistent across all platforms in all our global locations.”</p>
Engineer with a top tier oilfield services company located in Houston, TX
        </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Yes, and your code is...???

Comment: You need to be more specific in your question. Add the code that is breaking as well as any error logs to reflect what you are asking. We cannot simply guess what the problem is with no code to look at.

Comment: Just added it, I was having problems with this as this is the first time I post anything to a forum.

Answer (score 0):

High performance embedded technology from Corvalent is unlocking new oil and gas resources globally. Proudly made in the heart of oil country,long-life rugged computing solutions from Texas-based Corvalent significantly reduce cost of system ownership and protect revenue by ensuring non-stop performance of oil operations. As trusted advisors to the oil and gas OEM community, Corvalent readily integrates customers’ IP as part of system development – creating compatible plug-and-play solutions that refresh systems, streamline part numbers, reduce development time and assure simple onsite integration.
        

        • Long-life, rugged computing solutions developed along the Texas Gulf Coast and deployed in some of the most dangerous, remote and technically sophisticated environments on earth
• Environmentally-certified solutions, validated for shock and vibration, dust and corrosion, and extreme temperatures
• Customized solutions ensure system compatibility and avoid onsite system add-ons
• Reduce development time and integration headaches with a valuable design and manufacturing partnership
• Expertise in applications such as chemical analysis, fracking data collection, undersea robotic equipment, subsea systems, onshore/offshore surface logging and much more.

“We use Corvalent in the field inside our logging boxes. The reliability and stability Corvalent provides allows us to be consistent across all platforms in all our global locations.”

Engineer with a top tier oilfield services company located in Houston, TX